# How to load page like facebook page load asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How to make a page load like Facebook ?? I made a div with an `image[tool image]` on left side and its description `[textbox]` on right. There are many images on database ,how can I show other images in the same format..??

I tried it by creating 10 rows with 10 images and 10 textbox it is working but page load became slow.Don't know how to handle other images..
Now i am using multiple pages with 5 image and text box,is there any better option ?

Help me to learn.

Comment: Could you just turn up the brightness on your screen a little? It's a bit hard to see the code you've already tried...

Comment: do you mean [lazy load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html)?

Comment: @jackjop something like that..

Comment: To load content during scrolling, have a look at [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/).

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider thanks(y)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load content after the page has been downloaded on the client, you may want to look into [JQuery](http://jquery.com) and more specifically [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)